# Как удалить ключ из словаря python зная индекс?

Tags: python, словарь

Есть словарь:

```
ad_vocabulary = {'Сдам 1-к квартиру': {'Цена': '4000 грн.', 'Местоположение': 'Питер'}}
```

Знаю, то что ключ `'Сдам 1-к квартиру'` имеет 0 индекс.

Как я могу его теперь удалить без указания самого ключа?

Comment: откуда вы знаете, что этот ключ имеет 0 индекс? откуда вы вообще знаете про индексы в словарях?

Comment: в какой версии пайтона у словаря есть индекс ключа?

Comment: @Jack_oS, начиная с Python 3.7 порядок ключей словаря сохраняется в порядке вставки/добавления, следовательно можно говорить об индексе ключа. Хотя напрямую Python не поддерживает индексирование ключей словаря по порядковому номеру :)

Comment: ̶у̶ ̶д̶е̶в̶о̶ч̶к̶и̶ ̶н̶е̶т̶ ̶и̶м̶е̶н̶и̶  у словарей нет индексов)
`del ad_vocabulary['Сдам 1-к квартиру']`
удалит элемент.  `el = ad_vocabulary.pop('ad_vocabulary['Сдам 1-к квартиру']')` удалит элемент и запишет в переменную.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Начиная с Python 3.7 порядок ключей словаря сохраняется в порядке вставки/добавления, следовательно можно говорить об индексе ключа. Хотя напрямую Python не поддерживает индексирование ключей словаря по порядковому номеру. Но создав список ключей можно имитировать "удаление по индексу".

Пример:

```
In [16]: dct = {2: 22, 1: 11}

In [17]: _ = dct.pop(list(dct)[0])

In [18]: dct
Out[18]: {1: 11}
```

Comment: `.keys()` не нужен! ))

Comment: спасибо! про сохранение порядка с 3.7 слышал, но про механизм удаления через список ключей не подумал ((

Answer (score 4):

Можно ещё вот так, например, если таких индексов несколько:

```
d = {'1': '2', '3': '4', '5': '6'}
ind_to_del = [0,2]
d = {k:v for i,(k,v) in enumerate(d.items()) if i not in ind_to_del}
print(d)
# {'3': '4'}
```